# Do i have to install DNX on my server to serve asp.net 5 site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Thats really frustrating how hard is publish a website with asp.net 5. Very bad documentation, and all things said in internet does not work for me. Someone here already made it work? My server has iis 7.5. Do i have to install asp.net 5 on my server? I heard i do not need to install. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please be more specific as to the exact steps you are getting and the error it produces?

[This documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) walks you through step by step on how to configure your server to serve up ASP Core (ASP.net 5) applications

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

In Summary

- Install the HTTP Platform Handler
- Publish the site from visual studio to a folder (Publish -> File System)
- Copy the files to your server
- Create a new site in IIS and point it to the wwwroot folder of the copied site
- Unlock system.webServer/handlers
- Set application pool for the site to "No Managed Code"

Once you do this the site will run. I just confirmed by setting up a brand new machine and launching an ASP.net Core application.